# Can't get C to write and read serial port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

This is my first C program. hello world! I'm sure this is no problem for high school programmers these days, but they didn't have programming when I was in high school. :)

I want to write to a serial port until the string I write is echoed back to me. Then do other stuff. My code below runs for a few seconds and then claims to see the string and ends, even when it could not have actually seen the string. It behaves the same no matter what so, I obviously have something very wrong.

Yes, the serial device /dev/kittens is real and, from a terminal, bash echoed strings to /dev/kittens are received(echoed) on the serial port when the port is looped.

I would be most appreciative to anyone who could correct my mistakes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <errno.h> 
#include <termios.h> 


int fd;
char *buff;



int open_port(void)
{

 fd = open("/dev/kitens", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
 if (fd == -1)
 {
  perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/kittens ");
 }
  else
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

 return (fd);
}



int main()
{
int wr,rd;
open_port();

char msg[]="There are mice in the wire.\r";


do 
{
/* Read from the port */
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
rd=read(fd,buff,sizeof(msg));

/* Write to the port */
wr = write(fd, msg, sizeof(msg));
printf("debugging - Wrote to port\n");   
usleep(10000);

if (wr < 0) {
    fputs("write() to port /dev/kittens failed!\n", stderr);
    break;
            }
 } while (buff != msg);

if (buff=msg)
printf(buff, "String Found! Now do the work.");
/* 
 system("dostuff.sh);
*/

/* Close the port on exit. */
close(fd);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your call to `open()` uses `/dev/kitens`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes. It was a typo in my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First,

```
if (buff=msg)
```

is assignment, not comparison :) The latter is `==`.

Second,

```
if (buff == msg)
```

is actually pointer comparison, not string comparison. For string comparison, see `strcmp()` from C standard library.

Third,

```
char *buff;
...
rd=read(fd,buff,sizeof(msg));
```

`buff` is left uninitialized - there's no memory allocated for it, so you're happy enough it doesn't crash at all.

Well, there is more to check, but listed above is already enough to prevent the program from functioning correctly.

As an advice: try to put a debugging `printf` below the `read` line to see what is actually read from the port. And remember, the data read from the port is not guaranteed to be zero-terminated (see `zero-terminated strings` for reference), so you have to watch for this also (either add a zero after the actual data, or somehow limit string operations on the buffer, like using `strncmp()` instead of `strcmp()`).

Comment: I was about to comment the same thing until I saw yours. Touché

Comment: But what he really wants is `if (strncmp (msg, buff, strlen(msg)) == 0)`

Comment: iKiar: =) @ott--: right. I've just hinted where to look, since the man is studying :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I changed my comparisons to look like this:
    while (strcmp(buff, msg) < 0 );

Now it segfaults.

Comment: Right, that's because `buff` is still uninitialised. Either declare it as char buff[100] (i.e. fixed-size array of length 100), or look what `malloc()` and `free()` are for :)

Comment: and yes, `strcmp(...) < 0` doesn't mean the strings are simply not equal, it means that `buff` is prior to `msg` in alphabetical order. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/)

Comment: if (strncmp (msg, buff, strlen(msg)) == 0) as well as char buff[100] and while (strncmp (msg, buff, strlen(msg)) != 0); did the trick. Thanks to you and everyone else that helped.

Comment: strcmp/strlen on buff does need more setup, reading from a serial port might very well not result in a nul terminated string. And since the read() is done non-blocking, buff might not end up as an entire line/string, it might read nothing at all.

Answer (score 3):

I see many errors:

- You should always check the return value for errors. Your `open_port` function may return `-1` if it could not open the port, yet you continue in the main loop.
- You do not check the return from read, it may be -1, more likely so since you set NDELAY on the file.
- You do not initialize buf, it points to somewhere you don't know because it is not initialized. You might want to use `char buffer[1024]` or something like this.
- In C, comparing two strings is done using `strcmp`, memory using `memcmp`. You're comparing two pointers, not their contents.

I think this is enough for you to start fixing the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work:

```
while (buff != msg);
```

buff and msg are pointers.  You can't compare the strings using == or !=.  You have to use strcmp()

Answer (score 0):

Where dos `buff` point to? it is not initialized.

Also, remember that in C you cannot compare strings using `==`, or you would be comparing addresses of strings. And no `=` either, that is assignment. To compare strings use `strcmp` or `memcmp` if there is no NUL chars at the end and the lengths are known.